# Check if mouse is down or dragging file from local folder to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I want to Check if a user drags a file from outside the browser. so i can do some css magic (gonna place a overview over the div the can drag the file to).

My homepage is made with AngularJS.

I was thinking about using something like the JQuery MouseDown, but don't know how i can catch the event when it's not firing from the browser.

I been searching for this, and everything i find is only when you gonna fire the event from the browser.

So, do anyone have a idea or played with this before?

Comment: How about `dragover`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://buildinternet.com/2013/08/drag-and-drop-file-upload-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use browser events: dragover, dragleave and drop.

Attach a handler to $(window) and on "dragover" add a class (something like "file-dragging") to a tag. Might be a good idea to add it to tags like `<html>` or `<body>` so all your elements can respond to it.

Then on "dragleave" and "drop" you can remove that class.

All the rest is best done through CSS, like you said.